# How to get duplicates in sorted list with O(n) python

Tags: python-3.x, list, duplicates, big-o

Hear i have a list, and i have to get duplicates from it. So i can use solution like this:

```
arr = [1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5]

def get_duplicates(arr):
    duplicates = []
    for index in range(len(arr)-1):
        if arr[index] == arr[index+1]:
        duplicates.append(arr[index])
    return duplicates

print(*duplicates)
```

Ok, what if i have three or more duplicates in my list? I did something like that:

```
arr = [1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5]

def get_duplicates(arr):
    duplicates = []
    for index in range(len(arr)-1):
        if arr[index] == arr[index+1]:
        duplicates.append(arr[index])
    return duplicates

print(*set(duplicates))
```

Is that both my code works with O(n) or not? I just dont know what is speed of set() function in python, but i think that first for loop takes O(n),
if set() takes O(n), it doesnt matter, because finally i will have O(2n) = O(n) in this case.

Do i solve that task correctly, or my code is not effective? Smart people, help me please))
If u know how to do it in wright direction, explain me please.

Comment: The original code does not find duplicates that are not adjacent; you did not make clear if such duplicates were possible.

Comment: i am using set, because i need to get only duplicates from my list. If i will use only set without loop i will get from [1,1,2,3,4,4,5] -> [1,2,3,4,5], but i need to get finally 1,4

Comment: I will always have adjacent duplicates, because my list is always sorted on entry. I will never get [1,2,1,2,3,3,4]. In sorted list will be always [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,5] duplicates always adjacent.

Comment: The list being sorted would have been good to include in the question.

Comment: Your code (the body of the `if`, specifically) is not properly indented.

Comment: I wrote that my list is sorted in the head of my question.

Comment: You posted an *example* that *happens* to be sorted; you wrote nothing that would rule out a list such as `[3,2,1]` much less `[1,2,1,3,1]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a version that is clearly O(n):

```
def get_duplicates(arr):
    last_duplicate = None
    duplicates = []
    for i,v in enumerate(arr[1:]):
        if v==arr[i-1] and v!=last_duplicate:
            duplicates.append(v)
            last_duplicate = v
    return duplicates
```

Note that this assumes, as your original code does, that duplicates will be adjacent to one another.  It also assumes that the first duplicate is not `None`.

Comment: Thanks, and can i ask you, what can u say about append() method? I mean, How many time it gets - O(1), O(n)? append method inside for loop will not increase our big O to O(n^2)? Or append does not matter in this case

Comment: `append` is O(1).